# Return list where the elements are taken from lists in turns/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I need help transforming 2 lists into where the elements are taken from two lists in turns

```py
def combine_lists(a, b):
    """
    combine_lists([1, 2, 3], [4]) => [1, 4, 2, 3]
    combine_lists([1], [4, 5, 6]) => [1, 4, 5, 6]
    combine_lists([], [4, 5, 6]) => [4, 5, 6]
    combine_lists([1, 2], [4, 5, 6]) => [1, 4, 2, 5, 6]
    :param a: First list
    :param b: Second list
    :return: Combined list
    """
```

What i tried:

```
# return a[0], b[0], a[1], b[1]
    combined_list = []
    for x, y in range (len(a), len(b)):
        combined_list = a[x], b[y]
    return combined_list
```

Comment: It seems like you basically want the `roundrobin` documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def combine_lists(*l):
    return [j for i in zip_longest(*l) for j in i if j]
```

---

```
combine_lists([1, 2], [4, 5, 6])
# [1, 4, 2, 5, 6]

combine_lists([1, 2, 3], [4])
# [1, 4, 2, 3]

combine_lists([], [4, 5, 6])
# [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
[x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(a, b)) if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not as simple as @yatus, but you can use the following:

```py
def combine_lists(a, b):
    combined_list = []
    for e_a, e_b in zip(a, b):
        combined_list.append(e_a)
        combined_list.append(e_b)

    len_a = len(a)
    len_b = len(b)

    if len_a == len_b:
        return combined_list
    if len(a) > len_b:
        return combined_list + a[len_b:]
    # this means len_b is greater than len_a
    return combined_list + b[len_a:]
```

---

```py
>>> combine_lists([1, 2, 3], [4])
[1, 4, 2, 3]
>>> combine_lists([1], [4, 5, 6])
[1, 4, 5, 6]
>>> combine_lists([], [4, 5, 6])
[4, 5, 6]
>>> combine_lists([1, 2], [4, 5, 6])
[1, 4, 2, 5, 6]
```